# Bitbucket Pipeline, Artifacts between steps

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use the following pipeline in bitbucket to deploy to gcloud. The rest of the pipeline is missing but I know that works. The issue is when I get to step two the compiled CSS files are no longer existing. It appears to match what bitbucket suggest for using artifacts. I tried the following;

```
 artifacts:
   - **
   -public/assets/css/generated/style.css
   -public/assets/css/generated/*.css
   -public/assets/css/generated/*
   -public/*
   -public/**
```

.

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    pipeline:
     - step:
         image: node:4.6.0
         caches:
           - node
         script:
             - cd web-application
             - npm install
             - npm install -g gulp
             - gulp
             - ls public/assets/css/generated
             # - mv public/assets/css/generated/* ~/./
             - cd ..
         artifacts:
             - public/assets/css/generated/style.css
             - public/**

     - step:
        image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
        script:
          - cd web-application
          - ls public/assets/css/generated
```

[Artifacts showing in step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IDRd.png)

Comment: Could you also provide the folder structure of your project and elaborate why you use `cd web-application` and `cd ..`?

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add web-application/public/assets/css/generated/style.css